# Google.Apis, c#, google calendar api. does not set or change colorId

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
    public async Task UpdateEvent(long? itemId)
    {
        GoogleAppointmentEvent eventInfo = new GoogleAppointmentEvent();


        eventInfo = ...//get some event description 
        Event myEvent = new Event
        {

            Summary = eventInfo.Summary,

            //Location = "Somewhere",
            Description = eventInfo.Description,
            Start = new EventDateTime()
            {
                DateTime = eventInfo.Start,
                TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
            },
            End = new EventDateTime()
            {
                DateTime = eventInfo.EndPeriod,
                TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
            },
            ColorId = eventInfo.Color,
            Recurrence = new String[] {
        "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO"
    },
            Attendees = new List<EventAttendee>()
        {
          new EventAttendee() { Email = "my_email@gmail.com" }

            }
        };

        string test = "11";
        myEvent.ColorId = test;
            Event recurringEvent = _service.Events.Update(myEvent, "primary", eventInfo.EventId).Execute();
    }
```

I can change the values ​​of any property except colorId. I can change the values ​​of any property except this. It does not change when I change it or set new Event. When I use [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) with my params, it change colorId as other values. When I try to set invalid value, I catch callback with error, so validation for the value of this field is triggered. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: when you did the Try-it, did the value 11 work?

Comment: no, it didn't work. I can change the value only in google example api.

Comment: if it didnt work in the Try-it? You expect it to work here?

Comment: no, in Try-it a can change colorId and it will work, as like other values.

Comment: you said the value 11 didnt work in Try-it. Which is which?

Comment: it work in try-it. I sad "When I use Try this API with my params, it change colorId as other values.", i mean try-it in theirs api.